# How to not lose Intermediate Data in File

Tags: python, file, output, autosave

While Learning Python, we do Print to screen but eventually graduate to printing to output files... However most times all errors are not resolved in the code... In such cases the code aborts after running some 10 20 loops or say 80% of the code and then aborts.. However during this time the data that is printed to the file is lost as the file.close() is not executed.

In Python is there a way in which we can save the WIP file. I want to do this without closing and reopening the file once again multiple times in append modes. This will help in Debugging and also not losing the data that has been accumulated before the error was occurred.

After searching i did not find something like this .... if someone has or can give any ideas how to make a module for this that will be great... What we need is a generic catchall... in case of any error.. execute the catchall code to close the file and then exit from Python.

Comment: Show us the code. Generally you would do `with open(...) as f:` but it is highly unlikely that without closing the file disappears (simply because the interpreter closes all opened files when GC collects them). Something else has to going on in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the documentation of File objects : https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=flush#file.flush

Use the `flush` function. There is also a note on the doc with `os.fsync` function to be sure the data are written on the disc.

Comment: Besides flushing every now and then, you can disable caching all together: `f = open(.., buffering=0)`. In either case, beware of the performance hit!

Answer (score 2):

You can flush the internal file buffer by calling `f.flush()` on the file object in question.

Even better is to wrap the file access in a [with block](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with). If an exception is raised, the file is closed.

```
with open('tmp.txt', 'r') as f:
    do_stuff_with(f)
```

Comment: Apologies, But coming from a C background, I am more used to f.open() and finally f.close()... rather than the pythonic way of using with open.. will move to this way sooner of later....